# Using reactive extension to run a task by schedule

Tags: c#, .net, timer, scheduled-tasks, system.reactive

I've seen a lot of examples that shows how I can run a task using the RX framework by timer e.g.,

```
var timer = Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
            .Subscribe(q =>
                {   
                    Console.WriteLine("do something here " + q);
                });
```

I would like to know if it's possible, and if so, how can I use the RX framework to run a task by schedule, for e.g., every day at 12 midnight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have written is essentially it.  Use the `Timer` overload that takes a `DateTimeOffset` for the start time:

```
DateTimeOffset startTime = midnight;
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

var timer = Observable.Timer(startTime, interval).Subscribe(q => Console.WriteLine("do something"));
```

Answer (score 3):

As much as I like RX I suspect it is the wrong tool for this job. What you want is the [Windows Task Schedular](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28VS.85%29.aspx) which is an operating system service. It's a bit like the Unix `cron` service. You write schedules as XML files such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
This sample schedules a task to start on a daily basis.
-->
<Task xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Date>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</Date>
        <Author>AuthorName</Author>
        <Version>1.0.0</Version>
        <Description>Notepad starts every day.</Description>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <CalendarTrigger>
            <StartBoundary>2005-10-11T13:21:17-08:00</StartBoundary>
            <EndBoundary>2006-01-01T00:00:00-08:00</EndBoundary>
            <Repetition>
                <Interval>PT1M</Interval>
                <Duration>PT4M</Duration>
            </Repetition>
            <ScheduleByDay>
                <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
            </ScheduleByDay>
        </CalendarTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
        <Principal>
            <UserId>Administrator</UserId>
            <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
        </Principal>
    </Principals>
    <Settings>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
        <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    </Settings>
    <Actions>
        <Exec>
            <Command>notepad.exe</Command>
        </Exec>
    </Actions>
</Task>
```

to [schedule daily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notepad.exe run run. Obviouslly you can replace `notepade.exe` with an application of your choice, including one written in C#.

Why not use RX to do this. Given that this is an application that needs to be very very long running and not crash it is better to delegate this to a specialized service controlled by the OS.